# What's the difference between handling fields throught "accessor" and "copy"

Tags: copy, kotlin, accessor

I don't understand the difference between handling a field through accessor and copy method in Kotlin. It is like this:

**Accessor example :**

```
class Person(val name: String, 
             var age: Int)

fun happyBirthday(person: Person) {
    person.age++
}
```

**Copy method example :**

```
data class Person(val name: String, 
             var age: Int)

fun happyBirthday(person: Person) {
    person.copy(age = person.age + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
person.age++
```

modifies your existing `person` instance by incrementing its age by 1.

```
person.copy(age = person.age + 1)
```

on the other hand returns a new instance of `Person` that has the same properties as `person` does, except for the `age` that you've specified. As your sample code is right now, you're not assigning this new `Person` instance to anything, you're just throwing it away.

This `copy` method is useful when your class is immutable (all of its properties are `val`s) - instead of modifying it, it gives you an easy way to create a new instance that has mostly the same properties as the original.

Comment: good point! .. I just remarked that age in the first example is var and in the second one is val